# Make HTML/CSS/Javascript not properly running on Tablet

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, tablet

I have wrote some basic HTML with some CSS and JavaScript. The code asks the user to enter a password and the Javascript verifies the password and alerts the user the required info. This code functions properly on my desktop but as soon as I add the files to my Samsung Tablet only the HTML appears. The code I'm using is as follows. Currently running all files out of same fodler but would like to move main HTML to tablet Home and leav CSS and Javascript in another location but still be referenced.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dowlingcss.css"/>
    <title>
        Dr. Dowling
    </title>



</head>

<body>  
<script src="dowlingjs.js"></script>    
<img src="parasol.jpg" alt="Parasol Logo" height="250" width="750"> 



        <h1>Welcome Dr. Dowling</h1>


        <p>What is the answer?</P>

    <form>
        <input id="pass">

        <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">Login</button>
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myfunction()
{


var x, text;

 //Get the value of the input field with id="pass"
x = document.getElementById("pass").value;
var password = x.toLowerCase(); 
// If x is Not = to fatluke
if (password != "fatluke") 
{
    alert("incorrect");
}
else {
    alert("The CD is in room 125 under the bed");
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the files are located in the right place?

Comment: They are all located in the same folder.

Comment: Assuming you are on Android with Chrome, you should try opening [remote DevTools (developer console)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) and see the errors there, this may give you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code in this block of code for running and check after page load

```
window.onload = (function () {
// insert your code here
});
```

also, try with "window.getElementById()", I think it depends on your browser and version of web view on your tablet.